# What is "~[task/:na]" or "~[na:na]" in a Java stack trace?

Tags: java, aws-lambda

Java stack traces in AWS Lambda now include some extraneous new stuff at the end of each line:

```
at com.cth.rets.indexer.App.lambda$0(App.java:53) [task/:na]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:792) ~[task/:na]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:776) ~[task/:na]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[task/:na]
at com.cth.rets.indexer.App.lambdaHandler(App.java:47) [task/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$StreamMethodRequestHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:350) ~[na:na]
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:888) ~[na:na]
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:293) ~[na:na]
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:64) ~[na:na]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:104) ~[LambdaJavaRTEntry-1.0.jar:na]
```

What do all the little extra `~[...]` things mean?

Comment: `~` is a common symbol for "approximately", and `na` means "Not Avaliable".

Comment: oh yeah, I could have guessed that too :-) But it doesn't make any sense in a Java stack trace. And it wasn't there before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What do all the little extra `~[...]` things mean?

Logging frameworks will use the tilde to denote that the **class packaging information it displays might or might not be correct.**

For example, here's an exerpt from the [logback documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#xThrowable):

> when it is unable to guarantee the absolute correctness of the
>   information, then it will prefix the data with a tilde, i.e. the '~'
>   character.

An `na` to the left of the `:` means the **jar or resource** from which the method is being called is unknown and an `na` to the right of the `:` means the resource's **version** is unknown.